# Does the Googleapis userinfo endpoint have any limit when fetching data using an access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

My client sends the access token to the backend and the backend then passes the access token to the following url.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=access_token_here
```

All necessary info is then returned.

is there any limit to doing this? The [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) does not seem to have any such limit mentioned but I want to be certain before pushing this to production.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The UserInfo endpoint is a standard endpoint on most if not all authorization servers.  There is no limit to how much you can call it.  Its not going to eat up your quota if thats what you are worried about.

Unless google has added some limits, which they may have if you continue reading.  The userinfo endpoint is designed to return "some" user claims in response to the authorization process.  Basic profile info like name, ....

I have noticed that it does not always return all of the claims it should. For example sometimes it returns empty and I wont see the user name.

A number of years ago I asked the Oauth2 team at google about it and they said they do not guarantee that you will always get all the claims back.  This is probably to deal with any potential spamming.

If you want / need user info then you should go though the people api.